# Same capture groups and how to reuse them

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have the following regex in `sed` that works:

```
sed -i -E "s/customer_metadata[(]([0-9][0-9][0-9]*-([A-Z][a-z]-){0,1}[3-6]),([0-9][0-9][0-9]*-([A-Z][a-z]-){0,1}[3-6]),([0-9][0-9][0-9]*-([A-Z][a-z]-){0,1}[3-6])/\5,$NEW_DATA/g"  file
```

But I suspect that it could be simplified since the pattern of the capture group is repeated. Also the fact that I am counting with `\5` the second group due to having the `()?` in each group seems error prone.
Is there a way to improve this regex?

Comment: would you mind to post sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

- `[0-9][0-9][0-9]*` is the same as `[0-9]{2,}`.
- `([A-Z][a-z]-){0,1}` is the same as `([A-Z][a-z]-)?`
- Drop some parentheses.

Shortened expression:

```
customer_metadata[(][0-9]{2,}-([A-Z][a-z-]-)?[3-6],[0-9]{2,}-([A-Z][a-z]-)?[3-6],([0-9]{2,}-([A-Z][a-z]-)?[3-6])
```

Or just

```
customer_metadata[^,]+,[^,]+,([0-9]{2,}-([A-Z][a-z]-)?[3-6])
```

It depends on whether you need to be very careful and verify that the bits between the first two commas are on the correct format or not.

Or just

```
customer_metadata[^,]+,[^,]+,([^-]+-([^-]+-)?.)
```

to verify that the third comma-separated string is on the form `something-something-character` or `something-character`.

Comment: I used `{0,1}` because sed does not support optional grouping at least in mac

Comment: So basically the last part is different just for validation?

Comment: @Jim I don't know what your requirements are or what possible formats your data can be in. The last two regular expressions ignore the actual data between the first two commas, and the last one only cares about getting something that is delimited by one or two dashes after the second comma. Which one you use depend on how carefully you have to match the data.

Comment: @Jim `sed -E` on macOS _does_ support `?`.